# Is it possible to make a mongoDb objectId greater than 24 characters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Just a simple question I could'nt get the answer through the doc nor stackoverflow:

I'd like to encode a discriminating unique value for my documents in the object id. That way, the unique value can be computed or retrieved when parsing the object id.

The main advantage for me are:

- it's deterministic, so I can use it to seed my DB and create _ids before creating documents, or for using an upsert function
- more efficient while getting by the unique value since searching by _id is more efficient than searching by the unique field (unless you create a new index I guess)

Here is the function I am using to do such an job:

```js
export function convertNameToObjectId(ressourceName) {
  const slug = ressourceName.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/g, '')
  return Buffer.from(slug).toString('hex').padStart(24, '0')//.substring(0, 24) may not be needed
}
```

So 90% of the time this works great because the said unique value is less than 24 characters when convertes to hex string, but sometimes it's a bit larger and mongoose throw an error: `Cast to ObjectId failed for value "33333630303131323233335f626e6b41636e74" (type string) at path "_id" for model "bankAccount"`

Si is it possible to make 24+ character length objectId? Did I miss a configuration?

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think it's possible, simply because mongoose internally casts search parameters to ObjectId in methods such as `findById` etc so it will break at any cast point. In my experience, feel free to ignore, I have used the [UUID](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#uuid) schema type to store a deterministic value and then create a [Compound Index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/indexes/index-types/index-compound/#compound-indexes) across `_id` and your new `unique_id`. You could even drop the index on `_id` because it would work on `_id` on it's own too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @jQueeny 

Comment: Can't drop the _id index as far as I know, pretty sure it's mandatory as it is used for internal MongoDB operations

Comment: @user20042973 just tested and you are correct. Even with the unique constraints on the compound of `_id` + `_another` the `_id` index cannot be dropped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, ObjectId is not just 24 bytes, but very specific 24 bytes: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-types/#std-label-objectid Many frameworks (Mongoose included) rely on this.

Saying that, _id can be of any type, not necessarily ObjectId. Can be a unique string of arbitrary length, a number, or any other BSON type.

I find it easier to keep _id as generated ObjectId and create a separate unique index for application-level ids. Just to ensure better compatibility with tools/libraries and do not spend time debuging issues not related to work.

Comment: Ok  I would be glad to know more about `"_id can be of any type"` thing...I tried with a custom string but it didn't work. Should I just modify the `Schema` field to something else than `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`? Is there any drawback to do that?

Comment: In what way did it 'not work'? See [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#the-_id-field) and also elsewhere on the page that states (emphasis added): "_The field name _id is reserved for use as a primary key; its value must be unique in the collection, is immutable, and **may be of any type other than an array**. If the _id contains subfields, the subfield names cannot begin with a ($) symbol._"

Comment: As  user20042973 said - mongodb itself is happy with any type, but mongoose is a quite opinionated ORM built on top of the native driver, and whilst it provides some conveniences, it adds own restrictions and limitations. Not all of them are even documented.  There is an example of how to use UUID for _id fields in mongoose: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#uuid yet it clearly states that it's still recommended to use ObjectId, unless "you need to".